# how do I get directx media player to play one or more videos on a continuous loop in vb.net? When I try an error appears

Tags: vb.net, directx, media-player

how do I get directx media player to play one or more videos on a continuous loop in vb.net? When I try an error appears

Error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Here's my code so far:

```
Imports Microsoft.DirectX
Imports Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Dim PlayorPause As Integer = 0
    Dim MovieN As Integer = 0
    Dim NowPlaying As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    Friend WithEvents videoFile As Video
    Sub Pause()
        If PlayorPause = 0 Then
            videoFile.Play()
            PlayorPause = 1
        Else
            videoFile.Pause()
            PlayorPause = 0
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub Nextvid()
        videoFile.Dispose()
        Dim WindowSize As Size = Panel1.Size
        If MovieN > NowPlaying.Count - 1 Then
            MovieN = 0
            Nextvid()
        Else
            videoFile = New Video(NowPlaying(MovieN))
            videoFile.Owner = Panel1
            Panel1.Size = WindowSize
            videoFile.Play()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Video_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles videoFile.Ending

        Dim WindowSize As Size = Panel1.Size
        If MovieN > NowPlaying.Count Then
            MovieN = 0
        Else
            Dim CurrenN As Integer = MovieN - 1
            MovieN = MovieN + 1
            videoFile = New Video(NowPlaying(MovieN))

        End If
        videoFile.Owner = Panel1
        Panel1.Size = WindowSize
        videoFile.Play()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        NowPlaying.Add(" C:\Users\Adminx\Downloads\ShortestVid.avi")
        Dim WindowSize As Size = Panel1.Size
        videoFile = New Video(NowPlaying(0))
        videoFile.Owner = Panel1
        Panel1.Size = WindowSize
        Me.KeyPreview = True
        Me.MinimumSize = New Size(319, 444)
        Me.Size = Me.MinimumSize
        Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    End Sub
    Sub NextPress()
        MovieN = MovieN + 1
        Nextvid()
    End Sub

    Sub PrePress()
        MovieN = MovieN - 1
        Nextvid()
    End Sub

    Sub Watchbtn()
        Me.MinimumSize = New Size(660, 444)
        Panel1.Visible = True
        Panel1.Focus()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

In Video_End, replace

```
If MovieN > NowPlaying.Count Then
```

with

```
If MovieN > NowPlaying.Count - 1 Then
```